# Why I must add the tail 'Provider' to Service Name, when I used es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular version is 1.4.8.

I have a service defined with es-6 class

```
class OrdersService {
    ...
}

export default angular.module('services.orders', [])
    .service('ordersService', OrdersService)
    .name;
```

I want inject it to a other module

```
import ordersService from 'orders.service'

function routes($stateProvider, ordersService) {
       ....
}

routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', 'ordersService'];

export default angular
    .module('orders',[ordersService])
    .config(routes)
```

But Angular throw a exception said 'Couldn't found provider orderService'. But add tail 'Provider' to service made it work.

```
routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', 'ordersServiceProvider'];
```

In this article, author don't add but still work.
http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/using-angular-1-dot-x-with-es6-and-webpack/

```
class RandomNames {
  ....
}

export default angular.module('services.random-names', [])
  .service('randomNames', RandomNames)
  .name;




import randomNames from 'randomNames'

export default class HomeController {
  ....
}

HomeController.$inject = ['randomNames'];
```

Why I need to add 'Provider' to a service? Is there a api doc to declare that?

Comment: `function routes($stateProvider, $ordersService)` we don't use `$` with them.. may be that's what causing you the trouble

Comment: @Minato Thank you, and $ is a typing mistake. The exception raise on $inject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the angular `config` phase you may only use providers. Using `.service` (or `.factory`) is shorthand for creating a provider. You can also use `.provder` but then you have to create the provider more explicitly.

Providers and the `.config` phase are used for configuration of services for use in the app. Since you are not doing any configuration, you get no benefit from injecting the `orderService` into `.config`.

Perhaps you could inject it into [`.run`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngAnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) instead of doing this manually.

Add special comment on your constructor:

```
export default class HomeController {
   /*@ngInject*/
   constructor(randomNames) {
     this.randomNames = randomNames;
   }
}
```

Then add ng-annotate plugin to your build process and it will describe that injections for you.